# How to give parameters in SQL query having LIKE keyword

Tags: python, sql, string, sqlite, sql-like

I have a Workers SQLite table and I am trying to display all workers whose name starts with a particular character input by the user.

```py
letter = input("\nEnter starting letter of worker: ")
(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Workers WHERE Worker_Name LIKE '(?)%'", (letter,))).fetchall()
```

But I always keep getting this error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

But when I give like this, it works:

```py
(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Workers WHERE Worker_Name LIKE 'J%'")).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation in the query:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Workers WHERE Worker_Name LIKE ? || '%'", (letter,))
```

... Or use string concatenation in your application code:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Workers WHERE Worker_Name LIKE ?", (letter + "%",))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first method was the one which worked for me. I had tried the second method earlier but it was giving me the same error.

Comment: @Animeartist If the second gave you an error, you probably tried `LIKE '?'` instead of `LIKE ?`. A question mark inside a string literal is not a parameter, it is just a string with a question mark.